# Dependency Injection Error in Worker Service

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, worker-service

Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: ProjectName.WS.Worker':
Cannot consume scoped service 'ProjectName.Service.IServiceManager' from singleton
'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)

**Program.cs Code**

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = "Service Name";
})
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddSerilog();

})
.ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); 
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
   );

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>(); 
     
    services.AddScoped<IServiceManager, ServiceManager>();
    services.AddScoped<IRepoManager, RepoManager>();  

})
.Build();
```

await host.RunAsync();

**Worker.cs file Code**

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger; 
    private readonly IServiceManager _serviceManager;
    private readonly IRepoManager _repoManager;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceManager serviceManager, IRepoManager repoManager)
    {
        _logger = logger; 
        _serviceManager = serviceManager;
        _repoManager = repoManager;
            
    } 
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var ewr = _serviceManager.CountryService.GetAll(); 
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

**Service Manager File Code --**

```
public class ServiceManager : IServiceManager
{
    private IRepoManager _repoManager { get; set; }
    public ServiceManager(IRepoManager repoManager)
    {
        _repoManager = repoManager; 
        CountryService = new CountryService(_repoManager.CountryRepo); 
    } 
    public ICountryService CountryService { get; set; } 
}
```

**Remo Manager File Code --**

```
public class RepoManager : IRepoManager
{
    private AppDbContext _db;

    public RepoManager(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db; 
        CountryRepo = new CountryRepo(_db); 
    } 
    public ICountryRepo CountryRepo { get; private set; } 
}
```

**Country Service File Code --**

```
     public class CountryService : ICountryService
    {
        private readonly ICountryRepo _repo;
        public CountryService(ICountryRepo repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }
   }
```

**Country Repo File Code --**

```
public class CountryRepo : ICountryRepo
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _db;
    public CountryRepo(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

**AppDBContext file code --**

```
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Try adding the repoManager before the servicemanager. It is injected in servicemanager and the compiler might not be able to find it if its declared after it.

Comment: Your worker class is registered as a singleton and can therefore only accept singleton dependencies. You have registered IServiceManager as scoped. Here´s an article how you can resolve the issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

Answer (score 0):

The service can not be initialized using the constructor instead you should do it like this:

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var _localServiceManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceManager>();
                var ewr = _serviceManager.CountryService.GetAll();
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

[This is an example of microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service#rewrite-the-worker-class)

Comment: This is still fairly dangerous since the service is now effectively locked to being a singleton too. Instead, create the service inside the `while` loop.

Comment: The scope should also be within the loop, they are meant to be used for finite operations and then closed.